# PHP MySQL while loop as variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, while-loop

**What is the best way to accomplish this?**

I have a PHP function that outputs a MySQL while loop. It works fine, displays every row as expected. However, I need to not **echo** the results, but rather put them as a **variable** to work with preexisting code. Changing that obviously limits it to only one result currently.

I assume it's got to be inserted as an array of sorts. Thinking about looping a loop is making my head hurt haha.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Just do this,

```
 $result_rows = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $result_rows[] = $row; //or $row['fieldname'] if you're looking for something specific
 }
```

**Note:** MYSQL extensions are deprecated, use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL if possible.

Comment: And please use mysqli_fetch_assoc() :)

Comment: And also initialize the array before trying to append to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
$resultsArray = Array();

$statement = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $resultsArray [] = array(
        'field1' => $row["column1"],
        'field2' => $row["column2"],
        'field3' => $row["column3"]);
}
```